# Efficient algorithm for enumerating subsets of size k

Tags: algorithm

Is there a way to enumerate the subsets of a set `S` (given as array) of size equals to `k` in such a way that it takes `O(n^k)` time where `n` is the number of elements in the set. The enumeration with backtracking algorithms that I have seen run in `O(2^n)` time, and I was wondering if there was an improvement to this.

Comment: The backtracking algorithms that I have seen are usually `O(k n^k)` as long as they have logic to skip out early when you need `i` more elements and have `< i` elements less.  Depending on how they handle the arrays there might be another factor of `k` in there.

Comment: You can count how many times each number appears in the array and then you can enumerate the subsets without having to check for duplicates if you do it correctly.

Comment: Algorithm R on page 9 of this Knuth fascicle: http://kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf